# PyQt application close with error

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have some trouble with creating window application using PyQt. For example: we have the following class for GUI:

```
class SampleMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):   
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
         ...

    def hideEvent(self, event):
        ...

    def showEvent(self, event):
        ...

    def activate(self):
        ...

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        ...
```

What if we want to use it just for showing results and acept user inputs, and for all control logic we have another class, which use the instance of `SampleMainWindow` as a field:

```
class Programm:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = SampleMainWindow()
        ....

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
prog = Programm()
prog.window.show()
app.exec_()
```

So, if we create the instance of `Programm`, the application will run well, but on close we'll get an error that python.exe process could not be completed normally. But if the instance of `SampleMainWindow` is not a field of class:

```
class Programm:
    def __init__(self):
        win = SampleMainWindow()
        ....
```

application close well. What's the reason?

Here are the full version of Gui class:

```
class SampleMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

def initTray(self):
    self.icon = QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon()
    self.icon.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('Tray.png'))
    self.icon.show()
    self.icon.activated.connect(self.activate)

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    moduleglobalconstants.APP_RUNNING = True
    self.initTray()
    self.newSession = True

    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 600, 400)
    self.setWindowTitle('Eye: Recently Added Lines')
    self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')
    exitAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('Exit.png')
            ,'Exit'
            ,self)

    exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
    exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
    self.connect(exitAction
                ,QtCore.SIGNAL('triggered()')
                ,QtCore.SLOT('close()'))

    menubar = self.menuBar()
    fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
    fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)

    self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Exit')
    self.toolbar.addAction(exitAction)

    self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit()
    self.scrollPosition = self.textEdit.textCursor()
    self.textEdit.setReadOnly(True)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)

def hideEvent(self, event):
    self.hidden = True
    self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.ToolTip)
    self.setVisible(False)

def showEvent(self, event):
    self.hidden = False
    self.setVisible(True)

def activate(self):

    self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window)
    self.show()
    self.setWindowState(self.windowState() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimized | QtCore.Qt.WindowActive)
    self.activateWindow()

def questionDialog(self, caption = 'Message',text = "Are you sure?"):
    self.activate()
    msgBox = QtGui.QMessageBox(self)
    msgBox.setWindowTitle("Eye")
    msgBox.setText(caption);
    msgBox.setInformativeText(text);
    msgBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes| QtGui.QMessageBox.No);
    msgBox.setDefaultButton(QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes);
    return msgBox.exec_()

def criticalDialog(self,app, caption = 'Eye: Critical Error',text = "Impossible to continue working!"):
    self.activate()
    msgBox = QtGui.QMessageBox.critical(self,caption,text)
    moduleglobalconstants.APP_RUNNING = False

def closeEvent(self, event):
    reply = self.questionDialog()
    if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
        moduleglobalconstants.APP_RUNNING = False
        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()

def showNewLines(self, singleLine = None, lines = None, mode='insert'):
    if (mode == 'rewrite'):
        self.textEdit.clear()
    if lines:
        for line in lines:
            self.textEdit.insertPlainText(line.strip() + "\n")
    elif singleLine:
        self.textEdit.insertPlainText(singleLine.strip()+"\n")
```

Comment: I tried your code with some guts added to the main window but everything seems to run fine with no errors on exit. I do get an error if I change: `self.win = SampleMainWindow()` to `win = SampleMainWindow()` because the `__init__` is finishing and the local variable 'win' is no longer referenced. Can you give any more details as to what error you are seeing?

Comment: On linux I had this "problem" too. It _sometimes_ "closed" with a segfault. But I did not care much since the program worked fine, and also anything that had to be done at the closure was perfectly done... it was only the interpreter segfaulting just before closing properly.

Comment: The problem with that is that the OS might catch the exit status and display annoying dialogs; happens to me a lot in Ubuntu when I make some typos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with python's garbage collecting - as (almost) soon an object isn't referenced anymore it destroys it, so I guess the process doesn't terminate as long as the window wasn't garbage-collected.

You can try to add at the end `del Programm.window` or something like that (there's probably a better way of doing this, but I never programmed QT myself so I can't help you here)

Comment: It seems, that you are right...I've simply added the `del Programm.window ` before exit and the error disappeared, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

see this:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 
from PyQt4.QtGui import * 
import sys 

class MyWindow(QWidget): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None): 
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent) 
        self.label = QLabel("Hi, I'm a window", self) 
        self.button = QPushButton("&Quit", self) 
        self.connect(self.button, SIGNAL("clicked()"), QCoreApplication.instance(), SLOT("quit()")) 

        lay = QVBoxLayout() 
        lay.addWidget(self.label) 
        lay.addWidget(self.button) 
        self.setLayout(lay) 

    def closeEvent(self, event): 
        print "Closing the app" 
        self.deleteLater() 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    mw = MyWindow() 
    mw.show() 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

the solution is to implement closeEvent method

Comment: sorry I need to add and call self.deleteLater()